# Pandas - Replace row values based on multi-column match

Tags: python, pandas

This is a simple question but most of the solution I found here were based on one column match (mainly only ID).

```
Df1
'Name'    'Dept'   'Amount'    'Leave'
ABC         1         10          0
BCD         1          5          0



Df2
'Alias_Name', 'Dept', 'Amount', 'Leave', 'Address', 'Join_Date'
ABC             1        100       5      qwerty       date1
PQR             2         0        2      asdfg        date2
```

I want to replaces row values in df1 when both the `Name and Dept` are matched.
I tried `merge(left_on=['Name', 'Dept'], right_on=['Alias_Name', 'Dept'], how='left')` but it gives me double number of columns with _x and _y suffix. I just need to replaces the `Dept, Amount, Leave` in df1 if the Name and Dept are matched with any row in df2.

Desired Output:

```
Name     Dept     Amount     Leave
ABC        1       100         5
BCD        1        5          0
```

Comment: You can try hacking together a solution using `pd.DataFrame.combine()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_df = df1[['Name', 'Dept']].merge(df2[['Alias_Name', 'Dept', 'Amount', 'Leave']].rename(columns={'Alias_Name': 'Name'}), how='left').fillna(df1[['Amount', 'Leave']])
```

Result:

```
  Name  Dept  Amount  Leave
0  ABC     1   100.0    5.0
1  BCD     1     5.0    0.0
```

You can use `new_df[['Amount', 'Leave']] = new_df[['Amount', 'Leave']].astype(int)` to re-cast the `dtype` if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp column in both data frames which will be sum of both "Name" and "Dept". That column can be used as primary key to match

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# select rows that should be replace
replace_df = df1[['Name', 'Dept']].merge(df2, left_on=['Name', 'Dept'], right_on=['Alias_Name', 'Dept'], how='inner')
# replace rows in df1
df1.iloc[replace_df.index] = replace_df
```

Result:

```
        Name    Dept    Amount  Leave
    0   ABC      1       100    5
    1   BCD      1         5    0
```

Comment: What is the difference in ```replace_df = df1[['Name', 'Dept']].merge(df2, left_on=['Name', 'Dept'], right_on=['Alias_Name', 'Dept'], how='inner')``` and ```replace_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Name', 'Dept'], right_on=['Alias_Name', 'Dept'], how='inner')``` what is the purpose of ```df1[['Name', 'Dept']].merge``` ??